# megacli lost virtual disk raid configuration

Tags: raid, lsi, megaraid, megacli

I've been running centos on x64 with an LSI raid controller

```
            description: RAID bus controller
            product: MegaRAID SAS 1078
            vendor: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic
```

i was trying to delete one of my 6 virtual disks with megacli64 . the vd was 0.
so i run:

```
MegaCli64 -CfgLdDel -L0 -a0
```

and  it said:

```
Adapter 0: Deleted Virtual Drive-0(target id-0)
Failed while adding the configuration to OS.
```

being ultra stupid in my confusion i rerun the command
and noticed that my vd 1 (target id-1) was gone too.
By checking the configuration i found the Enclosure:Ids of the disks involved in my vd1 that got deleted too.
Is there any way to recreate the virtual disk without losing the data in the disks?
from the megacli manual i couldn't find a way to retag.

Thanks you all so much!

edit: in addition i'm trying to save the config then edit it and restore it but cfgsave fails

```
MegaCli64 -CfgSave -f raidconfmissingdrives -a0
Failed to get config data.
Exit Code: 0x01
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. so i managed to save my data.
It seems that megacli doesn't provide a way to create a new virtual disk without initializing it and losing all the data.
I rebooted the machine and entered the raid configuration utility hoping that i would be able to do it from there.
Sure enough in the VD settings tab i created a new disk group and then i added the disks
that were unconfigured. it has an option to initialize them , but left that unchecked. after a warning that this should be done only in recovery cases, it created the group and upon reboot 
everything was fine, apart from the disk UUID having changed. updated fstab with the new one
and all is now fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the RAID1 via the cli and skipped the initialization step. The created device was bootable and still had the OS. Somehow the logical drive was gone and the two individual disks were showing as Unconfigured(good) when looking at the physical drives.