# IBM x3650 accidentally deleted RAID5 Virtual Drive

Tags: megaraid, megaraid-storage-manager

I've got an IBM x3650 M3 server that I inherited. It's got 6 physical disks with RAID 5 using 0,1,2,3  and RAID 1 using 4,5.  Disk 3 has failed and now I'm getting   'Hard Disk 0 failed' and I can't even boot into the OS (Ubuntu).  To make matters worse, I panicked and somehow deleted the RAID 5 virtual drive.

Pictured below the RAID 5 used to be the Slot3 0-3 now foreign and unconfigured.  The good thing is I think the drives are still in correct order, I just can't figure out how to re add the Virtual Drive RAID 5.... Is there anything I can do?

[image]

From readings on the forums etc like here 
[megacli lost virtual disk raid configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/665106/megacli-lost-virtual-disk-raid-configuration?newreg=4ca01d7505984b26ac6df29f8b1a0feb)

I think I can re-add the array without initializing... BUT I can't get into the MegaCLI storage to create a Virtual Drive since there's no 'Storage' option.

[image]

I've figured out how to do it from the cli buuut I'm guessing that automatically initializes.

I'd really appreciate any suggesions... because, of course, I didn't back anything up on there. ,

Answer (score 1):

Sadly if two disk were tagged dead inside your RAID-5 array, it's finish, your data is lost.

The fact you erased or not the RAID-5 volume after changed nothing to that fact, nor maked thing worse, as your array was dead anyway.

If you need to start fast, maybe take the disk 2-3, and make a RAID-1 volume. After that it would be to restore from a backup... but as you have none, please re-install, I just hope your important file are on the RAID-1 volume

Comment: Hmm I only lost one disk, did I miss something?  Plus even if I rebuild it I'll need to get back into 'storage' somehow.

Comment: @DirkPitt hdd 3 failed, and the 0 after, thus make 2. " Disk 3 has failed and now I'm getting 'Hard Disk 0 failed' ".  Sadly it explain why you no longer can boot

Comment: Ah, no sorry! The stress is getting to me.  That was the original message on the screen, only one drive has ever been amber.  Once I accidentally deleted the Virtual Drive they all went amber, but only one is bad.  The rest are just unconfigured...

Comment: @DirkPitt oh, then the array erasure was a bad idea :( as all your member were online when you issued it, see there as maybe you can save it; https://serverfault.com/questions/610046/data-recovery-from-deleted-raid-array

Comment: I think it's worth a shot...however, under system settings, theres no "storage" option to add a virtual drive

Comment: Whew well its working again but definitely on its last legs.  Anyone looking for the solution: click on each physical drive, select properties and then select  Unconfig Good, this sets the drive back to an acceptable state.  Then click on Scan Drives and it should ask if you want to recover the Virtual Drive.  After that I rebooted even the OS  came back up again.   Making backup copies of everything as fast as I can!!! Thank you for the suggestions and help!!

Comment: @DirkPitt Thanks for the feedback,  glad to know it worked and how you did it.